# is there a way to validate groovy text is a simple value vs. a groovy script?

Tags: groovy

Let's say I have a parameter

```
 def param = //comes from somewhere else
```

I could run new GroovyShell().evaluate(param)

Since this could be quite dangerous.  Instead of running that, I am wondering if there is a way to convert to a type and NOT run any groovy code.  I simply want to verify the param is NOT groovy script and is an int/long/String/etc. some primitive and convert it to that primitive if possible.  **oh, shoot, also would like to convert string arrays to string of primitives too**.  I guess perhaps we may have to just parse it all out?  (Wondering if there is a different command to convert?)

Is there a way to do this?

example values coming in

- [56, 23, 56]
- ["asdf", "qwer"]
- "aswqer"
- 89

thanks,
Dean

Comment: try to parse it as json?

Comment: could you provide examples of values that are coming ?

Comment: hmmm, json might be an option actually!!!  That is a very very good idea @daggett

Comment: @daggett AWESOME, json parse worked perfectly!!!!  Man, why all the negative 1's.  stack overflow has gone downhill with all the haters on it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
import groovy.json.*

def parser = new JsonSlurper()

def okValues = [
'[56, 23, 56]',
'["asdf", "qwer"]',
'"aswqer"',
'89',
'true',]

assert okValues.count( parser.&parseText ) == 5

try{
  parser.parseText 'def groovy = "is cool"'
}catch( t ){
  assert t
}
```

Comment: This won't work for maps, if the input is an actual groovy map instead of a json object.

Comment: you mean that it won't work for `map.toString()` output? of course it won't!

Comment: Just wanted to point it out, as others might not be aware when reading this. And I don't mean `map.toString()` as that drops the quotes around strings, but a proper groovy map, e.g. `['a b': 'c d']`, as opposed to the JSON equivalent `{"a b": "c d"}`.

Comment: `['a b': 'c d']` is a Groovy-only literal and  does never occur anywhere else. Also, the OP didn't mentioned it...